# Cómo agregar una @firma (una imagen generada) a la ultima pagina del PDF con TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

estoy necesitando agregar una imagen generada en (Base64 y que sería una firma dibujada previamente) en la última pagina de un PDF. aquí va el código, que resulta esta agregando la imagen en la segunda hoja.

```
// Aqui va la firma con el recuadro
                        $imageArray = explode( ',', $action['image'] );
                        $imgdata = base64_decode($imageArray[1]);
                        $pdf->AddPage();
                        $pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata, 350, 190, 300, 300, '', '', '', true, 250, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
                        $pdf->lastPage();
```

La verdad necesito alguna mano. Gracias desde ya
la idea sería que aparezca así en la ultima hoja del PDF:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero... cual es el problema especifico que tienes? te sale algún error?

Comment: No sale ningún error, inserta la firma en la segunda hoja. Necesito que se genere siempre una última hoja y allí se inserte el gráfico.

Comment: Pero como esperas que te ayudemos, si no nos muestras que como estás manejan do el documento, que insertas en la primera página, que insertas en la segunda, como cierras el documento?

Comment: El Documento ya se carga por el usuario (no controlo eso) y ya viene de otro proceso en donde se firmo digitalmente, en este ultimo. tengo que insertar la imagen de la firma (esta en la bd) siempre en una hoja nueva al final de doc. insertar el certificado digital (crt) y guardarlo como otro doc. no se si me explique bien.